# Upgrading to 10.04 broke my TrueMobile 1150 wireless

Tags: 10.04, wireless, upgrade, dell, 8.04

My laptop was running 8.04 LTS (hardy), using network manager I believe, and the wireless worked fine. I do not believe I was using ndiswrapper, as the original version of Ubuntu I installed (edgy) just auto-detected everything. I did an upgrade to 10.04.3 LTS (lucid) and when I rebooted wireless networking stopped working. I can't even get it to connect to open wi-fi.

```
$ iwconfig eth1
eth1      IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:"MYESSID"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: None   
          Bit Rate:11 Mb/s   Sensitivity:1/0  
          Retry limit:8   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/70  Signal level=-122 dBm  Noise level=-122 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

lshw -c network output:

```
  *-network
       description: TrueMobile 1150 Series PC Card
       product: Version 01.01
       vendor: Dell
       physical id: 0
       slot: Socket 1
       resources: irq:5
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=orinoco driverversion=0.15 firmware=Lucent/Agere 9.48 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11b

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ pccardctl ident 1
  product info: "Dell", "TrueMobile 1150 Series PC Card", "Version 01.01", ""
  manfid: 0x0156, 0x0002
  function: 6 (network)
```

Comment: you can answer it now 10+ rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following command appears to have fixed the issue.

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename /lib/firmware/agere_sta_fw.bin
```

I did this per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/498336/comments/93